# How to make a camera to follow the player like it is attached by chain?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote a trivial script for camera to follow the player:

```
public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target;
    public float SmoothTime = 0.3f;
    public Vector3 Offset = new Vector3(0, 2, -3);
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = Target.TransformPoint(Offset);
        transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
            targetPosition, ref velocity, SmoothTime);
    }
}
```

It works as I need until the player is moving forward. BUT when the player turn right or left (always 90 degrees) I want to the camera waited until the player will move little far away and after the camera smoothly rotated and continued to follow him.

How to implement this behaviour?

[image: Sketch]

I hope it will make my question clearer.

**P.S.** There isn't walls in my game and the camera doesn't need to check collisions with walls.

**UPD**
I've improved my script:

```
public class SmoothFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform Target;
    public float SmoothTime = 0.3f;
    private float distance;
    private Vector3 velocity = Vector3.zero;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, Target.localPosition);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 offset = transform.position - Target.position;
        if (offset.magnitude > distance)
        {
            offset = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(offset, distance);
            Debug.Log(offset);
            transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
            offset, ref velocity, SmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation,
                Target.rotation, Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

This is more in line with what I need, but still far from smooth following.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/737568/camera-tether.html

Comment: @Jason, yeah, it is little similar there is a camera rotation that I need but I have a passive camera (there is not a camera controller in my game, it's just following the player). I can rotate camera according the player rotation but I don't know how to make it smoothly when the player will be little far away already

Comment: @Jason, in short the player have turned, for example, left already and is continuing to run but the camera is only beginning to rotate when the distance between them achieved a some limit.

Comment: You just need to check the distance to the player and if it's over a certain distance you need to either lerp or use an easing function to close the distance if you want a smoother movement. There's an easing function lib you can use: https://gist.github.com/Fonserbc/3d31a25e87fdaa541ddf - tbh though it looks like you are pretty much doing this..

Comment: What's the issue you are having with your current script? Do you have any clips?

Comment: @Charleh, I am trying to keep distance but my code fails. I've update my code in answer to the last version with clipping.

Comment: I don't see any videos of the camera problem - it would help with determining what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
    offset, ref velocity, SmoothTime);
```

Since `offset` is relative to the origin, when you interpolate between `transform.position` and `offset`, you will get strange results. The fix is this:

```
transform.position = Vector3.SmoothDamp(transform.position,
    Target.position + offset, ref velocity, SmoothTime);
```